# Can't create an instance from shell for a class that has a foreignKey

Tags: python, django, shell

So I was trying to populate my db from Django's shell (just testing). However when I try to create an instance from a class that has a ForeignKey nothing seems to work.

```
#models.py
class Pizza(models.Model):
    """Bleh"""
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

def __str__(self):
    """Devolve a representacao em string do model"""
    return self.name

class Topping(models.Model):
    """Ingredients"""
    pizza = models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

def __str__(self):
    """String rep"""
    return self.name

#shell commands
>>> from shop_app.models import Topping, Pizza
>>> p = Pizza(name='Hawaiian')
>>> p.save()
>>> t = Topping(pizza='?',name='Pineapple')
```

question mark stands for "no idea what should I put there".

I've tried many things, including 'Hawaiian', but none of them worked.
From the admin page it works correctly though. However that's not what I'm looking for

Comment: `pizza=p`?.....

Comment: @ShangWang no, you can't do the second of those; that's for querying, not for creating.

Comment: @Sayse I'm drunk, I just burnt my comment.

Comment: @ShangWang - Thats ok, it was Daniel Roseman that corrected you though. Happy drinking!

Comment: @Sayse Thx, man. Did something wrong previously here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this:

```
>>> from shop_app.models import Topping, Pizza
>>> p = Pizza(name='Hawaiian')
>>> p.save()
>>> t = Topping(pizza=p,name='Pineapple')
```

Comment: O_O" ! Thx mate! Pretty sure that did not work a couple of hours ago.